# Scrabble Tile Counter

Tags: java, beginner, programming-challenge, collections, enum

#### Introduction

Inspired by [this r/dailyprogrammer problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4oylbo/20160620_challenge_272_easy_whats_in_the_bag/), I've written a Scrabble tile counter.  Given a `Collection` of Scrabble tiles known to be in play, it can output a `Map` of the remaining unused tiles and their counts, which can be converted into a `Map` containing counts and a `Set` of tiles with that count.

> #### Description
>
> Scrabble is a popular word game where players remove tiles with
>   letters on them from a bag and use them to create words on a board.
>   The total number of tiles as well as the frequency of each letter does
>   not change between games.
>
> For this challenge we will be using the tile set from the English
>   edition, which has 100 tiles total. [Here's a reference for the
>   distribution and point value of each
>   tile](http://scrabblewizard.com/scrabble-tile-distribution/).
>
> Each tile will be represented by the letter that appears on it, with
>   the exception that blank tiles are represented by underscores _.
>
> #### Input Description
>
> The tiles already in play are inputted as an uppercase string. For
>   example, if 14 tiles have been removed from the bag and are in play,
>   you would be given an input like this:
>
> ```
> AEERTYOXMCNB_S
> ```
>
> #### Output Description
>
> You should output the tiles that are left in the bag. The list should
>   be in descending order of the quantity of each tile left in the bag,
>   skipping over amounts that have no tiles.
>
> In cases where more than one letter has the same quantity remaining,
>   output those letters in alphabetical order, with blank tiles at the
>   end.
>
> ```
> 10: E
> 9: I
> 8: A
> 7: O
> 5: N, R, T
> 4: D, L, U
> 3: G, S
> 2: F, H, P, V, W
> 1: B, C, J, K, M, Q, Y, Z, _
> 0: X
> ```

#### Feedback

- I'm a pretty new to Java so general pointers around design and implementation would be much appreciated.
- My biggest design qualm was around the implementation of the `ScrabbleTile` enum. `ScrabbleTile`s feel like they should be an enum, with the `character` and starting count that the tile is associated with.

  - The `isScrabbleTile` and `valueOf` methods are fairly inefficient - which makes me wonder if there's a better way to represent `ScrabbleTile`? Note: I know I haven't implemented anything that uses either but imagine the use case where a method takes in a `Collection` of `char`s and returns the tile count. It's something that I might implement in the near future.

#### Implementation

```java
public static class ScrabbleTileCounter {

  public static Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> calculateTileCount(final Collection<ScrabbleTile> tiles) throws NoRemainingTilesException {
    final Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> tileCount = new HashMap<>();
    tileCount.putAll(ScrabbleTile.STARTING_SCRABBLE_TILE_COUNT);
    for (ScrabbleTile tile : tiles) {
      if (tileCount.get(tile) < 1) {
        throw new NoRemainingTilesException();
      }

      final int nextVal = tileCount.get(tile) - 1;
      tileCount.put(tile, nextVal);
    }
    return tileCount;
  }

  public static Map<Integer, Set<ScrabbleTile>> calculateOutputTileCount(final Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> tileCount) {
    final Map<Integer, Set<ScrabbleTile>> outputTileCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<ScrabbleTile, Integer> entry : tileCount.entrySet()) {
      final Set<ScrabbleTile> scrabbleTiles = outputTileCount.get(entry.getValue());
      if (scrabbleTiles == null) {
        outputTileCount.put(entry.getValue(), new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getKey())));
      } else {
        scrabbleTiles.add(entry.getKey());
        outputTileCount.put(entry.getValue(), scrabbleTiles);
      }
    }
    return outputTileCount;
  }
}

public enum ScrabbleTile {
  A('A', 9),
  B('B', 2),
  C('C', 2),
  D('D', 4),
  E('E', 12),
  F('F', 2),
  G('G', 3),
  H('H', 2),
  I('I', 9),
  J('J', 1),
  K('K', 1),
  L('L', 4),
  M('M', 2),
  N('N', 6),
  O('O', 8),
  P('P', 2),
  Q('Q', 1),
  R('R', 6),
  S('S', 4),
  T('T', 6),
  U('U', 4),
  V('V', 2),
  W('W', 2),
  X('X', 1),
  Y('Y', 2),
  Z('Z', 1),
  BLANK('_', 2),
  ;

  public static final Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> STARTING_SCRABBLE_TILE_COUNT;
  static {
    final Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> startingScrabbleTileCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (ScrabbleTile tile : ScrabbleTile.values()) {
      startingScrabbleTileCount.put(tile, tile.getStartingCount());
    }
    STARTING_SCRABBLE_TILE_COUNT = Collections.unmodifiableMap(startingScrabbleTileCount);
  }

  private final char charValue;
  private final int startingCount;

  ScrabbleTile(final char charValue, final int startingCount) {
    this.charValue = charValue;
    this.startingCount = startingCount;
  }

  public char getCharValue() {
    return charValue;
  }

  public int getStartingCount() {
    return startingCount;
  }

  public static boolean isScrabbleTile(final char c) {
    for (final ScrabbleTile tile : ScrabbleTile.values()) {
      if (tile.getCharValue() == c) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static ScrabbleTile valueOf(final char c) {
    for (final ScrabbleTile tile : ScrabbleTile.values()) {
      if (tile.getCharValue() == c) {
        return tile;
      }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("unable to get Scrabble Tile for character: %s", c));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `ScrabbleTile` enum is overkill.  The tiles are mostly in consecutive ASCIIbetical order (except for the characters `[`, `\`, `]`, and `^` that we would consider as junk between `Z` and `_`).  A simple array, serving as a lookup table, would do the job:

```
private static final int[] START_COUNTS = {
    /* A */ 9, /* B */ 2, 2, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, /* M */ 2,
    /* N */ 6, /* O */ 8, 2, 1, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, /* Z */ 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, /* _ */ 2
};
```

It's much easier just to work with `char`s and `int`s directly.

---

Your `calculateTileCount()` function appears to implement the bulk of the counting work.  I find it to be an unnatural interface design, though.  The `ScrabbleTileCounter` doesn't act like an object, the way its name would suggest.  It's not obvious what "calculate" means, or that the `tiles` is a list of tiles to be removed from the initial set.  I would find an interface like this more intuitive:

```
ScrabbleTileCounter scrabble = new ScrabbleTileCounter();
for (char c : tiles) {
    scrabble.remove(c);
}
/* something here about scrabble.tileCount() */
```

I don't recommend marking function parameters as `final`.  Functions are usually short enough that it's obvious you haven't reassigned the variable.  The `final` adds noise, and it gives the false impression that the object is immutable, when in fact there is no such guarantee.

---

I don't think that you need to define a `NoRemainingTilesException`.  The standard `NoSuchElementException` is close enough to do the job.

Comment: [Suggested solution here](/q/132798/9357)

Comment: I also don't like the idea of an enum, but I'm not a big fan of your `int[] START_COUNTS` either, as if you want to change or check the start counts for 'J' for example, you'd have to count a lot. How about a `Map<Character, Integer>` ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg A `Map` seems like overkill for such a simple lookup table, but that's a matter of taste. You could also comment the array more generously.

Comment: If you use have to use comments that excessively to make the code readable, then it's a sign to me that you are initializing them in a bad way. How about reading the start counts from a configuration file and then transform it into an `int[]` ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg That would make a good answer on my follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

#### `EnumMap` over `HashMap`

For `enum` types, you can use [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) over a `HashMap` as a more efficient `Map` implementation.

#### `Map.put(K, V)` for an existing entry

```
  final Set<ScrabbleTile> scrabbleTiles = outputTileCount.get(entry.getValue());
  if (scrabbleTiles == null) {
    outputTileCount.put(entry.getValue(), new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getKey())));
  } else {
    scrabbleTiles.add(entry.getKey());
    outputTileCount.put(entry.getValue(), scrabbleTiles);
  }
```

You do not need the second `outputTileCount.put(entry.getValue(), scrabbleTiles` as `scrabbleTiles` is a reference to the *existing* map entry.

#### Copying `Map` entries

```
final Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> tileCount = new HashMap<>();
tileCount.putAll(ScrabbleTile.STARTING_SCRABBLE_TILE_COUNT);
```

Both `EnumMap` (see above) and `HashMap` lets you copy an existing `Map`'s entries using the constructor too.

```
Map<ScrabbleTile, Integer> tileCount =
                                new EnumMap(ScrabbleTile.STARTING_SCRABBLE_TILE_COUNT);
```